# Extract a word from a file

Tags: bash

I have a Podfile.lock file and I want to extract the framework version out of it (without parentheses). This is how the line looks like:

```
PODS:
- MyPrivateFramework (1.0.2.34)
```

I'm trying to use sed but nothing works.

I tried many things and this is the latest:

```
VERSION=$(sed 's/.*MyPrivateFramework (/\1/' Podfile.lock)
echo $VERSION
```

No luck.. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre on the right track; but there are many options. Here is one using `awk` and `cut`:

```
VERSION=$(awk '/MyPrivateFramework/ { print $3 }' Podfile.lock | cut -d '(' -f 2 | cut -d ')' -f 1)
echo $VERSION
```

gives:

```
1.0.2.34
```

Comment: then what does it give you?

Comment: that means your input file is not exactly as shown in your question... please provide the exact input lines....

Comment: I assure you, the input is correct, I just replaced the name of the framework. And using echo $VERSION as suggested

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101094/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-nimrod-shai).

Comment: Ok, i'm not sure what i've done, i deleted some things and than put it back. It looks the same now and it's working. Good enough for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[()]' '/MyPrivateFramework/{print $(NF-1)}' file

1.0.2.34
```

**Explanation:** set the field separator to open/close parenthesis, find the line with the keyword, print the penultimate field.

UPDATE: you can assign the output to a variable as usual

```
$ version=$(awk -F'[()]' '/MyPrivateFramework/{print $(NF-1)}' pods); echo $version
1.0.2.34
```

Comment: This one works but it prints the output. I only need it to put the version inside a variable

Comment: @NimrodShai, then go ahead and use a variable to hold the version number.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP 'MyPrivateFramework \(\K[^)]+' file
1.0.2.34
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/.*MyPrivateFramework (\([^)]*\).*/\1/p' file
1.0.2.34
```

Comment: as usual 15 million possibilities to do this. Advantage: you're using only one program!

Comment: Try: `grep -oP 'MyPrivateFramework\s*\(\K[^)]+' file`

Comment: With this one the project doesn't build

Comment: You need to clarify it further as shell script is not built it is a script after all. Does you grep not support `-P` option?